# Can a .NET rdlc report get data from DB2 Database?

Tags: c#, db2, rdlc

I'm working on a website(aspx webpages) that must generate reports. The idea is to use a rdlc reports with parameters(begin and enddate) to fetch data from db2 database.

i have a reportviewer that uses these rdlc report to show data.

I already did this with a sql server database but now i need to know if a .net rdlc reports is able to get data from a DB2 database? Actually in a rdlc report you define a datasource(dataset) where set your connection to a DB. can someone tell that there will be no problem in connecting to A DB2 databse?

thanks

Comment: What are you using to process that report?

Comment: If you are able to configure Reporviewer to use an ODBC data source, then you should be able to use ReportViewer with Db2. The *details* depend on the operating-system on which Db2 is running (Z/OS, i-series, Linux/Unix/Windows), but your question does not mention this vital detail.

Comment: Hi Marnix, i'm afraid that I don't know what you mean?? I'm kind a newbie when it comes to reports;

Comment: Hello Mao, the Db2 is running on a dedicated server  with Z/OS